# Mediawiki Special:UserLogin

Tags: mediawiki

I already made it to enter some additional text to the 
`mydomain/wiki/Special:UserLogin`.
I added a phrase:

> In order to apply for an account send an mail to…

But I have absolutely no clue anymore how I did that.

All the hints in the web apply to modify the standard text blocks by adding 
`?uselang=qqx` to the URL to see the appropriate MediaWiki pages...
But how did I make it to add this text to the `Special:UserLogin` page?

Answer (score 4):

On your wiki, go to the page `MediaWiki:Loginprompt`. The content of that page becomes the message that appears above the login screen at `Special:UserLogin`, so edit the page if you want to change the message.

Using the URL provided, that would be `mydomain/wiki/MediaWiki:Loginprompt`.